# UIButton target not recognized when adding button superview controller to another viewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I created a sub-class of UIViewController called toolbarViewController , I declare a UIButton in this view controller and specified it's target as following

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forContorlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then i do the following in a different view controller

```
toolbarViewController *toolbar = [[toolbarViewController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar.view];
```

the problem is that when i press the button i get the exception: Unrecognized selector ( doSomething ) send to instance , what am i doing wrong here ?

doSomething declaration in toolbarViewController.h

```
-(void)doSomething;
```

and in toolbarViewController.m

```
-(void)doSomething{ NSLog("doSomething got called"); }
```

Comment: Did you implement the `doSomething` method? If yes, in which class?

Comment: Is your doSomething accept parameter?Can you please show your doSomething definition?

Comment: of course i implemented doSomething,  i  did that in the toolbarViewController class

Comment: your **addTarget:self** need to be the the class obj where you have **doSomething** method e.g addTarge:yourCalassObj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the declaration of `doSomething`. If you declare IBAction something like `-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender`, you should add selector like

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forContorlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

instead of

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forContorlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: i changed the definition of doSomething to (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender and it worked just fine , thnx

Answer (score 1):

if you use ARC，you alloc toolbarViewController，but it has relese。you can try to this:

```
ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    toolbarViewController * toolbar;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) toolbarViewController * toolbar;


ViewController.m
@synthesize toolbar = _toolbar;


    toolbar = [[toolbarViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"toolbarViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

and you alloc button can do this:

```
UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        bt.frame = myFrame;
        [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(dosomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:bt];
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible case is if you add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIButton`'s superview.
On iOS5 it seems there is an issue with `UITapGestureRecognizers` that do not cancel the tap in view.

So all you need to do is set the

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

let me know if it helped!